# Get NullPointerException while running sonarqube analysis of my code

Tags: node.js, jenkins, sonarqube, node-modules

I have a Jenkins job to publish Unit test coverage (lcov format) to a SonarQube server as described in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600498/sonarqube-analysis-not-showing-code-coverage) and its answer. Sometimes, I see the following exception for JavaScript files in the `node_modules` directory in the Jenkins console log.

```
16:57:15.037 ERROR - Problem while calculating coverage for /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins-project-name/workspace/project-name/node_modules/js-tokens/test/fixtures/regex.js
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.UTCoverageSensor.saveZeroValueForResource(UTCoverageSensor.java:146) [sonar-javascript-plugin-2.9.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.UTCoverageSensor.saveMeasureFromLCOVFile(UTCoverageSensor.java:128) [sonar-javascript-plugin-2.9.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.UTCoverageSensor.analyse(UTCoverageSensor.java:85) [sonar-javascript-plugin-2.9.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76) [sonar-batch-shaded-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch8900787800742033772.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_79]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
```

I added the `node_modules` directory to exclusion lists:

```
sonar.exclusions=./project-name/node_modules/**/*
sonar.test.exclusions=./project-name/node_modules/**/*
```

But I still sometimes get the error. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your case is similar to a [known issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-569) which will be fixed in version 2.10 of the JavaScript plugin. This version should be released in the coming days.

As a workaround, setting up exclusions as you did should work. If you still get the same error, I suppose that the path you provide is not resolved correctly by SonarQube: you can try removing `./` at the beginning.

Comment: Removing the `./` at the beginning solved the issue for me. Thanks